# Angular 101: ngShow using object property not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Less "not working" and more "I think I'm not doing this correctly". Here is the relevant markup:

```
<select ng-model="strength">
    <option selected="selected" value="ALL">All</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>


<table style="" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-show="row.strength" ng-repeat="row in yearly | orderBy:'-year'">
            <td>{{row.season | season}}</td>
            <td>{{row.strength}}</td>
            <td>{{row.n}}</td>
            <td>{{row.a}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The purpose is to have, for each row, a strength of `ALL`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. I would like to show/hide the row based on the selected value. Is this the best approach?

Comment: Eh...the condition is always `true` for every value...is there a property in the object that is the same value as the row?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your intention correctly, you need to use an expression here. `ng-show="row.strength === strength"`.

Also note that you could achieve the same result by way of the `ng-repeat` with a filter that omitted values that didn't match `strength`. I think `ng-show` here is clear enough, though.

Comment: Hmmmm. This works to set the default show but doesn't update the show/hide when the select option is changed.

Comment: Can you post a working plnkr or jsfiddle? I think it should automatically update when the select is changed.

Comment: If i just put `row.strength == strength` in the `ngShow` attribute it's updated. Using curly braces doesn't have the update.